# Divide trapezoid into 4 equal parts.

Tags: geometry

Only thing figured out is that each part will have an area of:$$\frac{3*a*a}{8}$$
[If we take side of the square as $a$]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Hint:*** use the same shape halving all lenghts (so sides are $\frac12a,\frac12a,a,\frac12\sqrt2a$).  Can you fix them in the original figure?

Comment: Great hint! I was able to see the solution based off this answer..